# Android Image Control

Tags: android, android-image

I have a big problem. I want to create a control for android in which the user sees an image and over lapping this image are smaller icons/image which are positioned relative to background image.

The smaller icons can be selected.

I really do not know how to go about it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Can you add a picture or something?

Comment: say i have an image of map of USA, and i want to show a small icons on Washington, LA and Ny. and these icons should be clickable. also the icon color will change depending on our selections. so cannot keep a static image. and this should work on dpi n resolutions.

Comment: So basically you want a background image with stateful image buttons over top of it?

Comment: yes and also manage the position of the stateful images so that it works with differet dpi and reselutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by having a clean image as background, like this: [image: usamap]

and then you could have `TextViews` within a `RelativeLayout` with the names for example, and on every `textView` you can set the attribute clickable to your method.
Something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nevada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Oregon"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Cali"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="showState"
        android:text="@string/Nevada"
        android:textColor="@color/contact_map_text_color" />
```

and on your `activity/fragment` you will have your method that will be called by the `View`, in the example case: "showState"

*Edit:* its probably not the best approach but it certainly works

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ray. how do i manage different device dpi and resolutions??? or hardcoded layout_marginRight and layout_marginTop will work on all devices???

Comment: hardcoded resolutions should work for all devices but I wouldnt suggest hardcoding it, use the @dimen param but you will have to make 2 layouts for sure, the landscape and the portrait.

Comment: here is more info about the dimension xml in your values folder: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: so you would have something like android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/indiana_left_padding"